# Python Flask form in form - update part of registration process

Tags: python, forms, flask

I have an APP where users need to register.

I have one `form` for the registration data username email etc.

The user registers in the same process a company, which can have multiple categories.

In my DB I have a category table which has a fixed amount of categories, lets say 500.

While the user registers he can choose up to 10 categories for his company.

**PROBLEM:**

I dont want to display 500 categories on the page. I would like to have an input field where a user can try to search for categories which fit for his company.

**MY IDEA:**

I created a second `form_category`. I use this form to limit the query with sqlalchemy `%like%`, so I dont have to display all 500 categories. I limit them to lets say 20 categories and show only the relevant ones where the user input %like% applies:

```
searched_categories = session.query(Category).filter(Category.category_name.like('%'+form_category.category_search.data.strip()+'%')).limit(20)
```

**PROBLEM**

First of all I have now a form in a form. Both forms have the same action. And it seems the first submit button always is the active one, which means I now can only submit the `form_category`.

And even if I manage to fix this, the whole page will reload everytime and I will probably lose all the inputs from the fields before.

**MORE IDEAS:**

I could create one more view for this and store the already entered data in a cookie. My initial route would be `/register` and if a user searches for a categorie it becomes to `/register/<user-input>` but that feels wrong.

I could also removed the `form_category` and try to do everything with jQuery, but for people with `noscript` the site would be not usable.

**NICE TO HAVE**

Is there a way not to relaod the whole page if a form is submitted, I would like only to relaod the part of the page where categories are displayed.

**HERE IS SOME CODE:**

forms:

```
class RegisterUserForm(Form):
    # infos for user
    email = EmailField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(message="Geben Sie eine Email ein"), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Passwort', validators=[DataRequired(message="Geben Sie ein Passwort ein"), EqualTo('confirm_password', message=u'Passwörter stimmen nicht überein'), Length(min=5, message="Passwort muss mindestens 5 Zeichen lang sein")])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Passwort wiederholen')
    # infos for company
    company_name = TextField('Firmenname', validators=[DataRequired(message=u"Wie heißt Ihre Firma?")])
    # infos for category
    category_is_merchant = BooleanField(u"Händler")
    category_is_distributor = BooleanField(u"Großhändler")
    category_is_service = BooleanField("Diensleister")
    category_is_manufacturor = BooleanField("Hersteller")
    # etc...

class SearchCategoryForm(Form):
    category_search = TextField('Nach Branche suchen')
```

form in form in my jinja html file (I deleted the unimportant data):

```
<form class="col-xs-12" id="register-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('register', next=request.args.get('next')) }}">


    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}  
      <div id="content-company-data">
        <h2> Firmendaten </h2>
        <div class="content">

     <!-- some data -->

    <form class="col-xs-12" id="search-category-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('register', next=request.args.get('next')) }}">
    {{ form_category.hidden_tag() }}

    <div class="form-group">
    {{ form_category.category_search.label }}
    {{ form_category.category_search(class = "form-control", placeholder ="Branche") }}

    {% if form_category.category_search.data.errors %}
        {% for error in form_category.category_search.data.errors %} 
        <p class="flashes-error-form"> {{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn"> Branche suchen </button>

    </form>

    <!-- some data -->

        <button type="submit" class="btn register-button"> Jetzt Kostenlos Registrieren </button>

</form>
```

In my main py where I submit the forms (testing atm. with limit()):

```
# register site
@app.route('/registrieren', methods=["GET","POST"])
def register(): 
    if current_user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(url_for('logged_in'))
    else:
        form = RegisterUserForm()
        form_category = SearchCategoryForm()

        searched_categories = Category.query.order_by(asc("id")).limit(4)

        if form_category.validate_on_submit():
            print "cat form validates"                
            searched_categories = Category.query.order_by(asc("id")).limit(2)

            return redirect(url_for('register'))

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            print "user form validates"

            #adding data to DB here
            return redirect(url_for('unconfirmed'))

        return render_template('register.html', form = form, form_category=form_category, searched_categories=searched_categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a pure Python solution? Coz your requirement can easily be implemented client side using Ajax and auto complete tag addition jquery plugins

Comment: I already fixed it with an autocomplete function from JavaScript.

Comment: Thats not an answer btw. comments should go into comment section, otherwise you will be downvoted.